# IPhone - Move detailTextLabel within UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitableview, uilabel

I am building a UITableViewCell.  I am using the style UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle for my table view cell.  In the textLabel of the cell I have data that can require a wrap.  So to accomodate, I want to move down the detailTextLabel so that the wrapped text isn't covered by the text in the detailTextLabel.  I am attempting the following:

```
CGPoint tempPoint = tableViewCell.detailTextLabel.center;
tempPoint.y += 100;
tableViewCell.detailTextLabel.center = tempPoint;
```

I have tried similar approaches with the frame of the label, but I could not get it to move.  When I log the y of the center point before and after, I always see it start as 0 and then it is just 100 afterwards.  I am using the %f flag in NSLog to view the value.  This all occurs in the function:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I subclassed UITableViewCell and implemented the - (void)layoutSubviews method.  I moved the label in that method.

Comment: I had to do the same, in order to achieve this.